# Populating a javascript array with variables before return

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

## Populating a JavaScript array with variables

## [Old JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4qW9A/)

I'm attempting to create an array that looks like this

```
//mapping array
var mapping = [
    [ "[POSITION]" , $( ".position" ).val() ],
    [ "[NAME]" , $( ".name" ).val() ],
    [ "[TOWN/DISTRICT]" , $( ".town" ).val() ],
    [ "[REGION]" , $( ".region" ).val() ],
    [ "[COUNTRY]" , $( ".country" ).val() ],
    [ "[HOG/HOS]" , $( ".hoghos" ).val() ],
    [ "[TOURIST ATTRACTION]" , $( ".tourist" ).val() ],
    [ "[SECTOR1]" , $( ".sector1" ).val() ],
    [ "[SECTOR2]" , $( ".sector2" ).val() ],
    [ "[SECTOR3]" , $( ".sector3" ).val() ],
    [ "[PITCHER]" , $( ".pitcher" ).val() ]
];
```

out of a variable list here

```
//vars
var ie1 = "[POSITION]";
var ie2 = "[NAME]";
var ie3 = "[TOWN/DISTRICT]";
var ie4 = "[REGION]";
var ie5 = "[COUNTRY]";
var ie6 = "[HOG/HOS]";
var ie7 = "[TOURIST ATTRACTION]";
var ie8 = "[SECTOR1]";
var ie9 = "[SECTOR2]";
var ie10 = "[SECTOR3]";
var ie11 = "[PITCHER]";
```

I've been trying to push them in using this code

```
var mapping = [];

mapping.push({ ie1 : $( ".position" ).val() , ie2 : $( ".name" ).val() , ie3 : $( ".town" ).val() , ie4 : $( ".region" ).val() , ie5 : $( ".country" ).val() , ie6 : $( ".hoghos" ).val() , ie7 : $( ".tourist" ).val() , ie8 : $( ".sector1" ).val() , ie9 : $( ".sector2" ).val() , ie10 : $( ".sector3" ).val() , ie11 : $( ".pitcher" ).val() });
```

which will then update the text on a page using this

```
$(".CYB").html(function(index,text){
    for (var i = 0; i < mapping.length; i++) {
        text = text.split(mapping[i][0]).join(mapping[i][1]);
    }
    return text;
});
```

after this, the variables are updated with new values so that a page refresh isn't necessary

```
//new vars
var ie1 = $( ".position" ).val();
var ie2 = $( ".name" ).val();
var ie3 = $( ".town" ).val();
var ie4 = $( ".region" ).val();
var ie5 = $( ".country" ).val();
var ie6 = $( ".hoghos" ).val();
var ie7 = $( ".tourist" ).val();
var ie8 = $( ".sector1" ).val();
var ie9 = $( ".sector2" ).val();
var ie10 = $( ".sector3" ).val();
var ie11 = $( ".pitcher" ).val();
```

when I throw in an alert it's easy to see where it's going wrong as

```
//alert with array
alert(JSON.stringify(mapping));
```

outputs

[{ "ie1":"","ie2":"","ie3":"","ie4":"","ie5":"","ie6":"","ie7":"","ie8":"","ie9":"","ie10":"","ie11":"" }]

It's treating the variables as text rather than loading their values but I'm not sure how to fix this.

So in summary, I'm trying to reach a stage where I can input data into text boxes and have it update content on a page. If I want to make changes I wish to be able to do that without a page refresh by saving the variables I entered and having them loaded into an array.

I'd be grateful for any help.

## [Old JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4qW9A/)

## Edit:

I updated it slightly and this is now working more correctly... However I need to take the first variables out of the on click event and they aren't loading when I do. I would appreciate help in finding a solution to this problem.

For posterity: I changed

```
mapping.push({ ie1 : $( ".position" ).val() , ie2 : $( ".name" ).val() , ie3 : $( ".town" ).val() , ie4 : $( ".region" ).val() , ie5 : $( ".country" ).val() , ie6 : $( ".hoghos" ).val() , ie7 : $( ".tourist" ).val() , ie8 : $( ".sector1" ).val() , ie9 : $( ".sector2" ).val() , ie10 : $( ".sector3" ).val() , ie11 : $( ".pitcher" ).val() });
```

to

```
mapping.push([ ie1 , $( ".position" ).val() ],[ ie2 , $( ".name" ).val() ],[ ie3 , $( ".town" ).val() ],[ ie4 , $( ".region" ).val() ],[ ie5 , $( ".country" ).val() ],[ ie6 , $( ".hoghos" ).val() ],[ ie7 , $( ".tourist" ).val() ],[ ie8 , $( ".sector1" ).val() ],[ ie9 , $( ".sector2" ).val() ],[ ie10 , $( ".sector3" ).val() ],[ ie11 , $( ".pitcher" ).val() ]);
```

## [New JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4qW9A/3/)

Comment: Is your current problem that after the first time you click generate, any future changes are not reflected below CYB?

Comment: That's exactly it, I know it's because I have the first variables inside the click event... but when I move them outside of the event it doesn't load them (they return as null).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for your new problem is due to your `[PLACEHOLDER]` text getting overwritten the first time you click generate.  Therefore any future clicks have no text to replace.  I suggest you get around this by using `spans` with classes.  I've mocked up a solution on your [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4qW9A/6/).

Comment: This works like a charm, thank you very much. I'll update the question over lunch with your solution.

Answer (score 1):

Your first line says you're trying to create a two-dimensional array, but your code is creating an array with a single element that is an *object* because you've written `mapping.push( { ... } )` - note the curly brackets.

Instead, use:

```
var mapping = [
  [ie1, $( ".position" ).val()],
  [ie2, ...]
  ...
];
```

That said, you really should consider some alternate structure for your data - this mess of hard-coded variables with numeric suffixes indicates that you should be using arrays and loops to construct your data.  The way you're overwriting those `ieX` variables is also confusing.

Comment: This is my first time working with arrays, would writing a loop to go through the different variables be a more correct solution to this problem?

Comment: Also, updated the fiddle to a half/working solution based on what you said [new JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4qW9A/3/). Additionally I updated my question above. Do play with entering stuff into the text boxes and hitting generate. Right now I still require a page refresh when inputting new data which is less than ideal.